# SQL variable in SELECT statement

Tags: variables, sql-manager

This seems like it should be so easy but I'm doing something wrong.  I want to declare a value so that I can enter it once on top and then use it throughout my code.

A simple version of the code is below, but it doesn't work. I get no results when I run it, but if I take out the `declare` and just set it manually, I get results:

```
declare @orderno varchar
set @orderno = '739724'
SELECT ORDSIG.* FROM ordsig
WHERE ORDER_NO = @orderno
```

This is what I've tried.

As said above, I get no results from the query. It should be giving me data for `Order_NO`, but it does not. When I remove the `Order_no = @orderno`, and set it to a constant value as `Order_no = '739724'`, I get some data results.

Comment: You need to include your error, or what the problem is.

Comment: Do you get anything if you change the top two lines to something like   DECLARE @orderno AS varchar = '739724';